# Setting absolute limits on CPU for Docker containers

Tags: docker, cpu-usage, scheduler, lxc, cgroups

I'm trying to set absolute limits on Docker container CPU usage. The CPU shares concept (`docker run -c <shares>`) is relative, but I would like to say something like "let this container use at most 20ms of CPU time every 100ms. The closest answer I can find is a [hint from the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/docker-user/UF0GxTp3NHI) on using `cpu.cfs_quota_us` and `cpu.cfs_period_us`. How does one use these settings when using `docker run`?

I don't have a strict requirement for either LXC-backed Docker (e.g. pre0.9) or later versions, just need to see an example of these settings being used--any links to relevant documentation or helpful blogs are very welcome too. I am currently using Ubuntu 12.04, and under `/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/docker` I see these options:

```
$ ls /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/docker
cgroup.clone_children  cpu.cfs_quota_us   cpu.stat
cgroup.event_control   cpu.rt_period_us   notify_on_release
cgroup.procs           cpu.rt_runtime_us  tasks
cpu.cfs_period_us      cpu.shares
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe I've gotten this working. I had to restart my Docker daemon with `--exec-driver=lxc` as I
could not find a way to pass cgroup arguments to `libcontainer`. This approach worked for me:

```
# Run with absolute limit
sudo docker run --lxc-conf="lxc.cgroup.cpu.cfs_quota_us=50000" -it ubuntu bash
```

The necessary CFS docs on bandwidth limiting are [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/sched-bwc.txt).

I briefly confirmed with sysbench that this does seem to introduce an absolute limit, as shown below:

```
$ sudo docker run --lxc-conf="lxc.cgroup.cpu.cfs_quota_us=10000" --lxc-conf="lxc.cgroup.cpu.cfs_period_us=50000" -it ubuntu bash
root@302e651c0686:/# sysbench --test=cpu --num-threads=1 run
   <snip> 
   total time:                          90.5450s
$ sudo docker run --lxc-conf="lxc.cgroup.cpu.cfs_quota_us=20000" --lxc-conf="lxc.cgroup.cpu.cfs_period_us=50000" -it ubuntu bash
root@302e651c0686:/# sysbench --test=cpu --num-threads=1 run
   <snip> 
    total time:                          45.0423s
```