# How to use custom name in docker overlay network for containers network name?

Tags: docker, docker-network

When we set an overlay network, we can use containers *names* to resolve container addresses. That works fine.

Can I use some other, custom network name?

For example, if my container name is `foo`, can I resolve it in my overlay network by `bar`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, with the [option `--net-alias`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings) (network-scoped alias for the container, [proposal 18699](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18699)):

```
docker run -itd --name foo --net-alias=bar --net mynetwork busybox
```

Any other container on the same network will be able to `ping bar` (which references `foo`)

Comment: Thanx! Do you know if it is possible to change alias while container is up?

Comment: @игор I don't see that feature in the proposal. More generally, changing characteristics of a container *at runtime* is still very limited right now (cpu and memory resources, not much else yet: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34043844/6309)