# What's the difference between `cpus` and `cpu_count` in docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

The [docker-compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#cpu-and-other-resources) states that:

> **cpu_count**, cpu_percent, cpu_shares, cpu_period, cpu_quota, **cpus**,
> cpuset, domainname, hostname, ipc, mac_address, mem_limit,
> memswap_limit, mem_swappiness, mem_reservation, oom_kill_disable,
> oom_score_adj, privileged, read_only, shm_size, stdin_open, tty, user,
> working_dir
>
> Each of these is a single value, analogous to its docker run
> counterpart.

But the `docker run` [documentation they reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-resources) only mentions `cpus`. There's no mention of `cpu_count`:

> --cpus=0.000  Number of CPUs. Number is a fractional number. 0.000 means no limit.

So what does `cpu_count` do?

Comment: Both [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) and [`docker container run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_run/) mention that `--cpu-count` is a *"Windows only"* option.

Comment: I missed that. Thanks. Still, though, what does it do?

Comment: Based on what I found, `cpu_count` and `cpu_percent` are Windows only option. It seems `cpu_count` fix the number of CPU allowed (waiting for an integer) and `cpus` specify how much of the available CPU resources a container can use (wainting for a float).

Comment: These flags are used in order to [Limit a container's resources](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#cpu). For the Linux case, they are used to configure `cgroups` (see more here: [How to allocate 50% CPU resource to docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26841846/how-to-allocate-50-cpu-resource-to-docker-container) and [Resource management in Docker](https://goldmann.pl/blog/2014/09/11/resource-management-in-docker/#_cpu)). Maybe `cpu-count` is something similar for `hyper-v`.

Answer (score 0):

it is for windows. Here is the runtime level configuration that it gets passed to:
https://github.com/opencontainers/runtime-spec/blob/main/config-windows.md#cpu

Answer (score 0):

The `cpu_count` option is specific to Docker on Windows and sets the number of CPUs available to the container. This is different from the `cpus` option, which specifies how much of the available CPU resources a container can use. The `cpus` option expects a fractional number, where 1.0 represents all CPUs.In contrast, `cpu_count` expects an integer and directly sets the number of CPUs available to the container. This option is particularly useful in scenarios where you want to limit a container to a specific number of CPUs.

Answer (score 0):

This guy on docker forums talks about both:

https://forums.docker.com/t/what-is-the-difference-between-the-cpus-and-cpu-count-settings-in-docker-compose-v2-2/41890/6

They do the same thing, however one (cpu_count) is windows specific