# Hide node core count from docker container

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, multiprocessing

I am currently building a system that run services in individual deployments in a kubernetes cluster and require the limitation of visible cores inside the container.

Node Specs:
8 Cores
16 GB memory

When I deploy, log into the container and inspect the core count with python's `multiprocessing` module I get the following output:

```
In [1]: import multiprocessing
In [2]: multiprocessing.cpu_count()
Out[2]: 8
```

This output is correct seeing that my node has 8 cores.

What I would like is for the container to return a core count of 1 as the core count when running the same `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` command.

The example use case for this is as follows:

Developer creates an api services running python and gunicorn, gunicorn's default behaviour is to create workers for the number of cores available.

The above will be a problem when the pod is only allowed 100m CPU and 300m Mem as the 8 workers will at some point fill up the memory and the pod will crash, I also would like to hide this for the sake of potential confusion and unexpected behaviour when detecting resources programmatically.

I have tried using the `--cpuset-cpus=0` flag as it stood out as a potential solution, but from what I understand and experienced is that  this will merely limit the container to the specified core, which does not hide the other 7 cores.

Is there any way of doing this, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try this article it my help you how to set docer cpu limit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26841846/how-to-allocate-50-cpu-resource-to-docker-container

Comment: --cpuset is now --cpuset-cpus from what I can see and --cpus don't work either :/

Comment: if you always up for a single worker, why not just to set number of  gunicorn workers in config  i.e. `gunicorn --workers=1 --threads=1 main:app`

Comment: Yah you can do that, and that is fine, but as i pointed out if an app uses an automated/dynamic method for scaling up threads it will see 8 cores and create 8 threads while only having a fraction of 1 core

Comment: I have the exactly same requirement.

Answer (score -1):

You could have an environment variable `NUM_CPUS` that if it's present you should use it instead of `multiprocessing.cpu_count()`. Something like:

```
import os

num_cpus = os.getenv("NUM_CPUS")
if num_cpus is not None:
    cpu_count = max(round(num_cpus), 1)
else:
    cpu_count = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
```