# How to restart a docker container if it runs for a period of time

Tags: docker

I am implementing a service which create Docker container for short time execution task. The service receives requests from clients and create a Docker container to run the request. Then get the response from the container and send it back to clients.

I want to limit the execution time of the Docker container for example, kill the container if it runs more than 20 minutes. Is there a configuration I can set on the container to stop in 20 minutes? Or do I have to manually calculate the execution time in my service? What is the better way to achieve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to limit \`docker run\` execution time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48299352/how-to-limit-docker-run-execution-time)

Comment: You could add a `timeout` command to the image `CMD` and then add a restart policy to your Docker config.

Answer (score 2):

Docker itself does not provide such an option. Please refer to a long proposal [issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1905#issuecomment-342149279) on GutHub

You will need a combination of `timeout` utility and `docker kill` in aftermath to really kill orphaned container.