# Auto stop Docker container after particular duration

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to stop my docker container exactly after some duration like after 40 minutes from the time it's up. Is there any way in docker-compose to achieve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to limit \`docker run\` execution time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48299352/how-to-limit-docker-run-execution-time)

Comment: above link explains --stop-timeout .thats related to how docker handles your container when docker stop is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can see that this feature is getting discussed [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1905). However, you can try this [one](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1905#issuecomment-427014386). Uses docker commands to achieve this.

Comment: I am using docker-compose to run the image in container, all the required configurations are added in "docker-compose.yml". I will execute the following command "docker-compose up -d" where the "yml" file is located to run the build image. The  [link1](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1905) and [link2](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1905#issuecomment-427014386) you have shared might help when we run using "docker run" command.

Comment: Have a look at @b0gusb comment above.  You can do it using compose